# Ionic Cordova video file for upload service

Tags: cordova, video, file-upload, ionic-framework, uri

Have anyone succeeded in making a uploadVideo function for Ionic and Cordova framework, where you capture a new recording or pick an earlier recorded video from the device library and upload it to a remote service. Its seems that `$cordovaCapture` or/and `$cordovaCamera` only result in a URI that is a representation of the video -on, -to and -for the device itself. It is not the file itself and result in upload failure. Is there any way that my Ionic Cordova app can grab the file through its URI or is there another Cordova plugin or method that allow me to catch the video file that is recorded or chosen on the device?

My apps record and chose video code is shown below, but if you have another and working code, I prefer that you base your answer around it instead. In my code `videoPath` holds the URI to the file.

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])

.controller('VideoCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaCapture, $cordovaCamera){

 // Used by cordova-video(player)
 // to display recorded or choosen video
 $scope.data = {
    videoPath: ""
  };

  // Camera Capture Video function
  $scope.captureVideo = $scope.captureVideo = function(){
    var options = {
      quality: 50,
      limit: 3,
      duration: 15
    };

      $cordovaCapture.captureVideo(options).then(function(videoData){
      // Success! Video data is here
      $scope.data.videoPath = "file:/" + videoData[0].fullPath;
    }, function(err){
      // An error occurred. Show a message to the user
      console.log(err);
    });
  }

  // Choose Video from Device PhotoLibrary
  $scope.getPicture = function(sourceType){
  var options = {
    quality: 50,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    mediaType:Camera.MediaType.VIDEO
  };

    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData){
      // Success! Video data is here
      $scope.data.videoPath = imageData;
    }, function(err) {
      // An error occurred. Show a message to the user
      console.log(err);
    });
  }


});
```

Comment: you can try to use the file-transfer plugin to upload the video, it should work with the file url